# getJSON - working on response and displaying error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I have a JSOn method as below:

```
$("#pwdOverride").change(function(){
        alert("Inside onchange");
        var pwdOverride = $("#pwdOverride").val();
        alert("value of pwdOverride... "+pwdOverride);          
        $.getJSON(
            '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/transaction/authenticationChk.do',
            {paramFilter:'PROFILE',pwdOverride:pwdOverride},
            function(data){
                alert(JSON.stringify(data)); -> return would be "pwd" or "aPwd" or "err"
            }
        )
        .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
        .error(function() { alert("error"); })
        .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });                   
    });
```

JSOn response would be a String either "pwd" or "aPwd" else "err".
Based on the result I would want to display an inline error message similar to the validaiton rules.

like

```
messages: {
            pwdOverride :"Incorrect pwd.",
            cpwdOverride: "Incorrect sec pwd."
}
```

Is it possible? if so how do i achieve?

Comment: inline error message? are you talking about angularJs here?

Comment: No. error message in line with the field that is validated using validate rules and messages. something similar otherwise. Not angular JS